# Apache doesn't want to Start - XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

Now the first thing I did was change the port it was using. I opened up the `httpd.conf` file, changed all port `80` to port `8080`, and it still doesn't want to start. Here is the error log:

```
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:21.108418 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 288:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:21.759466 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 288:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:22.895556 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 288:tid 540] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:22.896593 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 288:tid 540] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:22.896593 2016] [core:notice] [pid 288:tid 540] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:22.906555 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 288:tid 540] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9520
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:24.245663 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 9520:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:24.727697 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 9520:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jan 13 11:23:24.797699 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9520:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

httpd.conf has these changes:

```
ServerName localhost:8080
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080
```

Comment: Looks like error is with your local `ssl.conf` file get included. Try to start after commenting it out from include in `httpd.conf`

Comment: @KailashYadav That works. Did you want to make that the answer so I can approve it as being the answer?

Comment: I have added it. It would be great if you upvote so that it helps other people on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like error is with your local `ssl.conf` file get included.
Try to start `apache` after commenting it out from **include** in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score -1):

8080 is another port used by programs such as Reporting Services etc. Why not try a different one and see if it still does not start.

Comment: User Kaliash Yadav's suggestion worked for me. It started on port 8080 now. Just waiting for him to submit it as an answer so I can approve it.